# What is the .ssh/config corresponding option for ssh -N

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I want to set up an alias in my config file that has the same result as this command:

```
ssh -N devdb -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234
```

---

My .ssh/config entry for `devdb`:

```
Host devdb
User someuser
HostName the_hostname
LocalForward 1234 127.0.0.1:1234
```

---

What do I put in the above config to not start a shell?

Comment: +1 for good question which got me thinking about how to make tunneling to random things quicker (i don't do it often enough to remember the switches, but i usually use the same ports, it's only the host that changes).

Comment: http://notaverb.com/setup

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So in `ssh.c` for OpenSSH 7.6p1 we find

```
            case 'N':
                    no_shell_flag = 1;
                    options.request_tty = REQUEST_TTY_NO;
```

so `-N` does two things:

- the `no_shell_flag` only appears in `ssh.c` and is only enabled for the `-W` or `-N` options, otherwise it appears in some logic blocks related to `ControlPersist` and sanity checking involving background forks. I do not see a way an option could directly set it.
- according to `readconf.c` the `request_tty` corresponds to the `RequestTTY` option detailed in `ssh_config(5)`.

This leaves (apart from monkey patching OpenSSH and recompiling, or asking for a `ssh_config` option to toggle `no_shell_flag` with...) something like:

```
Host devdb
 User someuser
 HostName the_hostname
 LocalForward 1234 127.0.0.1:1234
 RequestTTY no
 RemoteCommand cat
```

Which technically does start a shell but that shell should immediately replace itself with the `cat` program which should then block allowing the port forward to be used meanwhile. `cat` is portable, but will consume input (if there is any) or could fail (if standard input is closed). Another option would be to [run something that just blocks](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/justblocks.c).

Comment: +1 for doing it within `.ssh/config`...well done!

Comment: Awesome research on this answer! Thank you!

Comment: I prefer `RemoteCommand exec sleep infinity`.

Answer (score 3):

@thrig has the right answer based on your desire to do this solely within `.ssh/config`

One might also consider using a function with defaults to make other tunnel commands quick (especially if the tunnel does not change but only the host).

---

```
sshn() {
  # set your desired host and port forwarding as default
  # and allow them to be passed in if you should need it

  host="${1:-devdb}"
  port="${2:-1234:127.0.0.1:1234}"

  # now all you have to do is `sshn` and it will connect

  echo "executing ssh -N $host -L $port"
  ssh -N "$host" -L "$port"
}
```

---

Here are three examples of it in use:
with no args the defaults specified in the function are used:

```
$ sshn
executing -N devdb -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234
```

with tunnel default, run on a different host:

```
$ sshn host2
executing ssh -N host2 -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234
```

with both defaults, run a full one-off to a new host/tunnel:

```
$ sshn host3 12345:127.0.0.1:12345
executing ssh -N host3 -L 12345:127.0.0.1:12345
```

Answer (score 0):

A more useful remote command based on @thrig's answer:

```
Host someHost
Hostname 1.2.3.4
LocalForward 15673 localhost:15672
RequestTTY no
RemoteCommand bash -c 'echo "Listening on port 15673"; read -r -d '' _'
```

The `read -r -d '' _` will block the connection until user press `control+c`.